# Making Bracha on Channukah Candles in Jail

Tags: blessing, chanuka, menora-chanukia, prison-jail

Someone who is in jail and is able to light Channukah candles, can/should he make a bracha?

I don't know if being in Jail is considered to be like having a home that someone would have a chiyuv to light candles in. This is a dira bal korcha (a forced living situation.) He definitely isn't paying rent in order to be there either. Is this like a "guest". Does the fact that he eats most of his meals there mean something as well?

Are there any poskim that discussed this issue?

Update: I later saw in the Beis Yosef in Siman 677 towards the end where he brings from the Mahari Abohav that someone who is in a boat or in the house of non-Jews may light with a bracha. Perhaps one may bring a proof from here to our case? Is the house of a non-Jew better/worse (in terms of being able to light with a bracha as he points out) than a jail?

Comment: http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/67882/jewish/Candles-Behind-Bars.htm

Comment: There would also be the question of his ownership of the candles, would there not?

Comment: @SethJ Why? What's the question ("lechem"?!) Let's say they got them from an outside source and were given to them.

Comment: @DoubleAA Very nice story...Although I don't understand why before this Yid came from South Africa he the Rebbe didn't push someone to organize Chanukah Candles in NY for the Prisoners? Without any success!? Surprising for Chabad and how persistent the Rebbe was. ZY"A...

Comment: Isn't a guest also obligated to light candle? What exactly is your hava amina that the inmate would be exempt.

Comment: @DoubleAA I said nothing about being "exempt". The shailo is in the bracha. You think the comparison between a normal "guest" and an inmate is the same? In regards to "who" is the inmate a guest?

Comment: @Yehoshua The question is is he obligated or not. If we conclude we are in doubt then we will rule to light but not to say a bracha. But it's all the same question. You can't just ask about the bracha.

Comment: @DoubleAA In a situation where a person wouldn't be "chiyuv" to light candles, if he does may he make a bracha?

Comment: @Yehoshua I don't understand your question. You only make a birkat hamitzva before doing the mitzva.

Comment: @DoubleAA Someone who is "patur" from Ner Channukah. If he lights the candles in the proper place and time may he make a bracha?

Comment: @DoubleAA In any case the shailo was accepted enough that it got +4 votes here as well as the Rov who I discussed it with seemed to appreciate the shailo. As well I heard R' Eliyashuv was asked -- however he gave conflicting teshuvas on different occasions. If you're not mispoel from the shailo it doesn't bother me so much, I'm in good company so far.

Comment: @DoubleAA see update to the question.

Comment: Rabbi Baruch Levine in his Sefer *Touched by a Niggun* [writes](https://lyrics.fandom.com/wiki/Baruch_Levine:Flickering_Lights) that a prisoner lights in jail, but he doesn’t say anything about making a Beracha. Then again, perhaps you can’t bring a proof from a song.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Per [Rabbi Ben Zion Abba Shaul](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=30504&st=&pgnum=6) in an essay in [Ohr Olam](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=30504&st=&pgnum=13&hilite=) one in prison should light and make a Bracha on Chanuka candles.

See [the conclusion of the essay here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=30504&st=&pgnum=15).

See also this, from a [talk](http://www.chabad.org/therebbe/article_cdo/aid/2603995/jewish/Motzoei-Shabbos-Parshas-Vayeishev-Mevarchim-Chodesh-Teves-5739-1978.htm) by R' Menachem Mendel Schneerson in 1978:

> It is of particular importance to reach those Jews who are confined to
>   hospitals and prisons, and to help them to light Chanukah candles.

Comment: Great source. How did you get to this?

Comment: Your link to the Sichos in English is now dead, בד"א. Are they still online somewhere?

Comment: @Isaac Nice! How'd you find that link?

Comment: @Shokhet I googled the quotation.

Comment: @IsaacMoses Ah. Good move!